# Animation Transition

Tags: ios, animation, uikit

I have my function below that would animate a transition from the cell item to a view controller. It seems that the toViewController subviews would have its full width when the animation begins (the blue part and toolbar on attached gif). Any idea on why it is happening?

[image]

```
class CardPresentationAnimator: NSObject, UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning {
    var originFrame: CGRect

    init(originFrame: CGRect) {
        self.originFrame = originFrame
        super.init()
    }

    var duration: TimeInterval = 0.7

    func transitionDuration(using transitionContext: UIViewControllerContextTransitioning?) -> TimeInterval {
        return duration
    }

    func animateTransition(using transitionContext: UIViewControllerContextTransitioning) {
        guard let toViewController = transitionContext.viewController(forKey: .to) else {
            return
        }   

        let containerView = transitionContext.containerView
        let finalFrame = transitionContext.finalFrame(for: toViewController)

        let animationDuration = transitionDuration(using: transitionContext)

        // Set the presented view controller the frame same as the origin frame
        containerView.addSubview(toViewController.view)
        toViewController.view.frame = originFrame

        UIView.animate(withDuration: animationDuration, animations: { 
             toViewController.view.frame = finalFrame
        }) { (finished) in
            transitionContext.completeTransition(finished)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Where are you setting the value of `originFrame`? Are you sure it's correct? Print the values of `containerView.frame`, `originFrame` and `finalFrame` --- see if they are what you expect them to be.

Comment: i think the frame values for me are just fine since in the animation above the  resizes and positions the views accordingly. The problem seems to be that the toViewController's view is getting the finalFrame width immediately during the animation then position itself accordingly.